# Parse scientific integer representation in perl

Tags: perl, parsing

What is the most elegant way to parse an integer given in scientific representation, i.e. I have an input file with lines like

```
value=1.04738e+06
```

Sure I can match the all the components (leading digit, decimal positions, exponent) and calculate the result, but it seems to me there is a more straight-forward way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
% perl -e 'print "1.04738e+06" + 0'
1047380
```

You just need to coerce it to a number and Perl will DWIM.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: `looks_like_number()` from `Scalar::Util` might come in handy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

my $line = "value=1.04738e+06";
my ( $tag, $value ) = split /\s*=\s*/, $line, 2;

if( looks_like_number( $value ) ){
  $value = 0 + $value;
}
print "$tag=$value\n";
```